# Сигнал завершения программы pyqt5. Выполнения кода после закрытия окна

Tags: python, pyqt5, subprocess

Мне нужно связать программу с интерфейсом PyQt5 и скриптом через `subprocess`. Связать получилось, но как оказалось, дочерняя программа не убивается автоматически после завершения основной программы.

Прочитал, как убивать дочерние скрипты в `subprocess`, но не знаю, куда этот код вставлять в основной программе.

Припустим, есть следующий код:

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class main(QWidget):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(500, 150, 1000, 763)
        self.show()

process = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'name.py'])
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = main()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Куда вставлять код, когда завершится эта программа? Моим опытом проверено, что код после последних строк не выполняется интерпретатором.

Comment: @AlexF Ну, как я понял, sys.exit(n) - закрывает приложение. А как тогда условие поставить на это, чтобы код впихнуть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я рекомендую вам изучить класс `QProcess`.

Класс `QProcess` используется для запуска внешних программ и связи с ними.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Terminal(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(readOnly=True)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        self.process = QtCore.QProcess(self)                             # !!!
        self.process.setProgram(sys.executable)                          # !!!

    def runFile(self, url):
        self.process.setArguments([url])
        self.process.start()                                             # !!!

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.process.close()                                             # !!!                                           
        event.accept()    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Terminal()
    window.runFile("test_floa2.py")                   # !!! тут ваша 'name.py'
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]